# TeXWork not typesetting

Tags: preview

I am new to TeXworks. I have a tex file and when I open it it shows fine but when I click on the Green arrow nothing happens and the Window > Go To Preview is greyed out. What am I doing wrong? As I am new do not know what info you need to help me.

Thanks

Les

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which TeX distribution are you using? MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: TeXworks version 0.6.6 (as shown in the HELP > About TeXworks), pdfLaTeX

Comment: That is only the editor. type on a terminal `pdflatex --version` and add the result to your question please.

Comment: I'm sorry but do not know what you mean by "a terminal".  There are other numbers in the HELP section. r.24442ac, GNU version2, Qt v5.15.2. I am running Windows 10 on a PC.

Comment: Type the command in the address bar of Explorer; or, better, type it in a DOS box at the prompt (WinLogo+R, then type cmd to open a DOS box).

Comment: Use @ to ping a user in the comments, otherwise they will not know you have typed something. The compiler version info will look something like `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) .....` (I have TexLive2020 distribution.)

Comment: If you open a new document from template (select article.tex) and there are no previews after saving  and clicking the green arrow mean that  you have selected the wrong compiler (e.g. pdtex instead of pdflatex) or something is not well installed. If it works the first time "as is" but no after some edit, mean that  you have introduced some fatal error in the code. Note also that if you see a PDF  just after open a .tex file with texworks, mean that exists a PDF with the same filename, but no necessarily is the preview of the actual code.

Comment: Hi everyone. Tried the option that Fran offered and still did not work. Uninstalled and reinstalled and tried again and still did not work.  When trying to use explorer to run "pdflatex --version it just did a normal web search. When running the command in DOS got an error "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Comment: Seems you have not installed an TeX distribution like MiKTeX or TeX Live. Install one of them ...